# Python Timer2 call function every n milliseconds on Pi

Tags: python, timer, scheduler

I'm using [timer2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/timer2/0.1.0) in Python to save data from an IMU sensor into a file every 10 miliseconds (100Hz). I tell to timer2 to run the function every 10 ms with the method "[apply_interval](http://ask.github.io/timer2/introduction.html#examples)".
However, the timestamp show that the function is called irregularely and too many times (1 per ms)

I need to save the data at the same precise interval in order to perform machine learning.

I will be happy if you could fix it with me.

Here is the code :

```
from numpy import linalg as LA
from conf import *
import RTIMU
from ledFunctions import *
import timer2

class IMU():

def retrieve_data(self):
    t = time.time()
    timestamp = t - self.last_time
    self.last_time = t

    accel = self.data["accel"]
    gyro = self.data["gyro"]
    mag = self.data["compass"]
    f = open(self.nameFile, "a")

    f.write(str(accel[0]) + ";" + str(accel[1]) + ";" + str(accel[2]) + ";" +
    str(gyro[0]) + ";" + str(gyro[1]) + ";" + str(gyro[2]) + ";" +
    str(mag[0]) + ";" + str(mag[1]) + ";" + str(mag[2]) + ";" + str(timestamp) + "\n")

    f.flush()
    f.close()

def __init__(self):
    self.last_time = time.time()
    print("Using settings file " + SETTINGS_FILE + ".ini")
    if not os.path.exists(SETTINGS_FILE + ".ini"):
        print("Settings file does not exist, will be created")

    self.s = RTIMU.Settings(SETTINGS_FILE)
    # Create IMU object
    self.imu = RTIMU.RTIMU(self.s)

    print("IMU Name: " + self.imu.IMUName())

    # Init IMU
    if (not self.imu.IMUInit()):
            print("IMU Init Failed")
            sys.exit(1)
    else:
            print("IMU Init Succeeded")

    # This is a good time to set any fusion parameters

    self.imu.setSlerpPower(0.02)
    self.imu.setGyroEnable(True)
    self.imu.setAccelEnable(True)
    self.imu.setCompassEnable(True)

    # Check if save directory exists
    self.imuDir = ifDirExists(imuDirectoryName)

    nameFileNum = self.imuDir + "/nb"
    # Check if nb file exists
    if not (os.path.isfile(nameFileNum)):
        fnb = open(nameFileNum, "w")
        fnb.write(str(0))
        fnb.flush()
        fnb.close()
        nb = 0
        print("nb file does not exist, create it")
    else:
        fnb = open(nameFileNum, "r")
        nb = int(fnb.readline().strip())
        fnb.close()
        print("nb file exists")

    # Create new file with name = nb + 1
    nb = nb + 1
    self.nameFile = self.imuDir + "/" + str(nb) 
    try:
        f = open(self.nameFile, "a")
        # Increment the value in nb file
        fnb = open(nameFileNum, "w")
        fnb.write(str(nb))
        fnb.flush()
        fnb.close()

        self.lastDisplay = time.time()
        self.poll = self.imu.IMUGetPollInterval()
        self.deltat = 0
        self.now = self.lastDisplay = time.time()
    except IOError as e:
        print "I/O Error({0}): {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror)

    # Retrieve data when available
    if self.imu.IMURead():
        self.data = self.imu.getIMUData()
    timer2.apply_interval(100, self.retrieve_data)

def loop(self):
    # Retrieve data when available
    if self.imu.IMURead():
        self.data = self.imu.getIMUData()
```

Thx :)

Comment: can you post complete code ?

Comment: maybe you have more than one thread ? Is this a single thread environment? Is this the complete code?

Comment: This code is launched in a thread from a main program starting 3 different threads. However, i'm trying to print time.time() every 34 ms in the python console and it doesn't work either... Intervals between two prints are different from 34 ms...

Comment: My best guess is that your problem lies somewhere. Perhaps write thread info while logging  .. you can use threading.get_ident()  or threading.current_thread()